# como centrar thumbnails en una pagina web?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg" class="rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" col-md-3">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg" class="rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" >
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg" class="rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Lo que quiero hacer es que las 3 imagenes aparezcan centradas en la pagina. Como se puede hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes centrar usando `flexbox`

```
<style type="text/css">
   .centrado{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
   }
</style>
```

Eso estaria en tu contenedor `padre`, o tambien puedes varias el `center` por `space-between` o `space-around`, depende como mejor te parezca

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una clase nueva en tu documento;

```
  <style type="text/css">
   .centrar_contenido{
  text-align: center;
}
```

tu html quedaria así;

```
  <div class="row centrar_contenido">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg" class="rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" col-md-3">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg" class="rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3" >
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kpvKA0vhaT0/maxresdefault.jpg" class="rounded img-thumbnail img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mmm no fuincionó, sigue exactamente igual

Comment: @facundorotger verificarlo bien ya que he probado antes de comentarlo.